# Why can we assume these inequalities without loss of generality? (Measure Theory, the Lebesgue Integral)

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am reading "Introduction to the Lebesgue Integral" (in Japanese) by Yoiti Yosida.

There is the following proposition in this book:

> Let $I := [a, b), I_i := [a_i, b_i)$ for $i \in \{1, \dots, n\}$.
> Let $|I| := b-a, |I_i| := b_i-a_i$ for $i \in \{1, \dots, n\}$.
> If $I \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} I_i$, then $|I|\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n} |I_i|$.

And the proof is the following.

> Proof:
> Without loss of generality, we can assume $$a_1\leq a <b_1,$$$$a_n<b\leq b_n,$$$$a_{i+1}<b_i\leq b_{i+1} (i=1,\dots,n-1).$$
> $$b-a\leq b_n-a_1=(b_1-a_1)+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(b_{i+1}-b_i)\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} (b_i-a_i).$$

Why can we assume the above inequalities without loss of generality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are just ordering the intervals from left to right. There is one interval that contains $a$ and we may reaname that as $(a_1,b_1]$. Next $b_1$ must be in some interval and we may call that $(a_2,b_2]$ [unless the first interval already convers the whole of $[a,b]$]. And so on until you reach $b$. Note that $b_1 \in (a_2,b_2]$ gives $a_2 < b_1\leq b_2$ etc.

Comment: Kavi Rama Murthy, Thank you very much for your elegant answer again!